# Can't install App on Apple Watch

Tags: iphone, applications, install, apple-id, apple-watch

I have a new Apple watch that I want to add the All Trails app to.  I have had the All Trails app on my iPhone for several years, and when I open the Watch App I can see All Trails under the list of additional apps that can be installed.

On my iPhone I am logged into the Apple ID that was used for installing All Trails, but I believe that I was using a second, different Apple ID when I paired the watch with my phone (I have 2 Apple IDs, one for personal use and one for my business usage)

When I initiate a download of All Trails, I see this:

[image]

I have tried logging the phone into the other Apple ID, but received the same message.

Why can't I install this App, and what can I do to get past this issue?

Comment: On your phone, go to Settings > General > iPhone Storage and locate AllTrails. Use the Offload App button then redownload it - you can try your original or new Apple ID.

Comment: @Ezekiel How will that affect the In App purchases I have made for All Trails?  I am paying for the All Trails subscription.

Comment: What Apple ID are you subscribing from? I would still recommend doing this exercise as it won't impact your subscription - but do it from the same Apple ID you're subscribing from.

Comment: @Ezekiel The subscriptions is from the Apple ID that I am currently logged into (and the one I am trying to download All Trails from), and not the Apple ID that I was using when the phone was paired.

Comment: I would still recommend redownloading using the process to ensure the information is all correct on your phone. You will not lose any data.

Comment: @Ezekiel I offloaded All Trails when signed in as Apple ID #1 (ID originally used to install All Trails).  I then signed in with Apple ID #2 (used when pairing the phone), but under the "iPhone Storage" it still said All Trails was installed.  So I offloaded it again, and did a re-install.  But was asked for the password to Apple ID #1

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I don't think I have anything to offer then. A call to Apple support might be a good next step if nobody else has ideas

Comment: @Ezekiel It turns out it was my confusion.  I did not realize that when signed in as ID #2, I could download an install Apps purchased under ID #1.  This time when it asked me for the password to ID #1, I entered it, and All Trails was installed when logged in under ID #2 (also used to pair the watch).  Then I used the Watch App and it did install All Trails on my watch.  Success!  What you suggested was the basis for the solution.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted - you can write up a self-answer and document what worked and self-accept so that this question is marked resolved. I'm not going to since I'm not 100% certain what exactly you did that helped so I'll leave that to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the situation, and how I (apparently) solved it.

**Initial situation**

- Apple ID #1 was used to install All Trails on my iPhone
- Apple ID #2 was used to pair my new Apple Watch with my iPhone
- I could not download the All Trails App to the Apple watch, no matter what Apple ID I was signed in as on the iPhone, even though the Watch App was saying that I could install it.

**Apparent Fix**

Based on Ezekiel's suggestions, I eventually did this:

1. When signed in as Apple ID #1, I went to Settings > General > iPhone Storage > All Trails, and clicked on "Off load App"
2. I signed out of Apple ID #1, and signed back in as Apple ID #2
3. I went to the App Store, and found the All Trails App, and clicked on "Update"
4. The App Store then requested me to input the password for Apple ID #1 (and this is also where I was confused for a bit, as I assumed you had to be signed in with the corresponding Apple ID in order to download from the App store)
5. After entering the Apple ID #1 password, All Trails installed
6. After All Trails was installed, I was then able to install the Apple Watch App.

I think that the trick was getting the All Trails App installed under the same Apple ID that was used for pairing the Apple Watch.  However, the error messages from Apple were not clear about this.

In addition, there is no easy way to know what Apple ID was used to install an App on the iPhone.  The best way I found was to try and do an update from the App store.  If it works straight away, then you are signed in with the Apple ID that was used to initially install the app.  If it asks for a password, then you are not signed in with the correct Apple ID (but at least the App store tells you what Apple ID was used).

Finally, I'm not sure I regret having a 32 character password (with a mix of upper and lower case letters, numbers and symbols) for one of my Apple IDs, but it sure made the process of swapping from one Apple ID to another a "fun" experience.